# Pass the rendered template HTML string to an external function

Tags: templating

I want to use all of the Craft features to render a page from template, but instead of serving it to the front-end visitors I want to send it to an external mail delivery service (something like MailChimp) using cURL.

I guess I need to get the rendered HTML into a string and then pass it to my cURL function. How can I achieve this, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build a plugin that fetches the HTML string and then passes it on to cURL or whatever you choose.

For a specific solution on how to get a template HTML string with all the parameters you need [check out this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2688/258)